# Can a C++ base class member function be written to instantiate whatever derived class it's called from?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, generic-programming

Is there any way to implement, just once, a function in a base class that will return an instance of whatever derived class it is called from?

Comment: [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <class TDerived> class Base
{
    TDerived retInstance()
    {
        return TDerived();
    }
};

class Derived : Base<Derived>
{
    //class definition here
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned,

1. CRTP (Curiously Recurring Template Pattern)
2. Or Cloneable Pattern.

---

## 1. CRTP

See it **[Liv on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5100c05c803b7319)**

```
template <typename Derived>
struct BaseImpl
{
    // normal stuff
    int foo() const { return 42; }

    // CRTP stuff
    Derived make_new() const 
    {
        return Derived("test 123");
    }
};

#include <string>

struct MyStruct : BaseImpl<MyStruct>
{
    std::string value;
    MyStruct(std::string const& value) : value(value) {}
};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    MyStruct a("first");
    MyStruct b = a.make_new();

    std::cout << a.value << "\n"
              << b.value << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
first
test 123
```

---

## 2. Cloneable pattern:

See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8c841ff53991c40)** too

```
struct ICloneable
{
    virtual const char* whoami() const = 0;
    virtual ICloneable* clone() const = 0;

    virtual ~ICloneable() throw() {}
};

#include <string>

struct A : ICloneable
{
    virtual const char* whoami() const { return "struct A"; }
    virtual ICloneable* clone() const { return new A; }
};

struct B : ICloneable
{
    virtual const char* whoami() const { return "struct B"; }
    virtual ICloneable* clone() const { return new B; }
};

#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;

    ICloneable* aclone = a.clone();
    ICloneable* bclone = b.clone();

    std::cout << typeid(*aclone).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << typeid(*bclone).name() << "\n";

    delete aclone;
    delete bclone;
}
```

Prints (compiler dependent):

```
1A
1B
```

Comment: Your clone example would be more relevant to the question if you get rid of the `IClonable` interface, make `B` derive from `A`, and have `A` declare a virtual `clone()` method that `B` overrides.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I choose to present the typical pattern. Also, I don't see how it would be more relevant. Simply remove B, rename `{ IConable -> A }` and `{ A -> B }` and you arrive at your sample. If you don't want pure virtuals, implement it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to the following [C++ code example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1ed9696b02b4f94) if your language of choice supports [covariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29) return types:

```
struct A {
    virtual A *make() = 0;
};

struct B : public A {
    B *make() override {
        return new B{};  
    }
};
```

While this doesn't fit your criteria of defined once in the base class, I think it is worth mentioning.

Comment: I didn't initially see the `c++` tag so you can ignore the covariant return type comment.